# 4k display flickering on HP z24s monitor on 60 Hz with DP1.2

Tags: windows-10, amd-radeon, display-driver, 4k-resolution, refresh-rate

About a year and half ago I bought a new 4k monitor: HP Z24s.
The very first batch.
And there has been a constant disappointment. I decided to not return the display to the shop, because everything else was perfect, i.e.: colors, overall quality, price, etc.

The monitor is connected to Radeon R9 390 8G Sapphire Nitro adapter with 3 meters DisplayPort 1.2 cable.
The problem only appears when I try to set the refresh rate to 60 Hz.
On 30 Hz everything works as expected.
Sometimes, the problem is solved when I set the refresh to 30 Hz, restart 
Windows 10 LTSB, and then set the refresh rate back to 60 Hz again.

The cable isn't the problem -- I tested it using another display on 60 Hz and everything worked fine. I also tried the cable using different R9 graphics cards (all from different manufacturers). The problem also persists when using another cable altogether.

I starts when I play a full-screen game, or sometimes at seemingly random times with no obvious cause..

Also, I updated monitor driver, and some time it looked good, but with every second AMD driver update I get this problem off and back.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem, or have a similar experience with this display?

P.S.: On Linux Mint 17..18, everything works like a charm -- no flickering on 60 Hz, both with opensource and proprietary drivers. However, on Mint 18 the are opensource only. And Windows, there is no difference if I set the color depth for HP monitor to 8-bit or 10-bit per color.
So bandwidth is not the issue probably.

Comment: "ut with every second AMD driver update I get this problem off and back." Keep a copy of a driver that works and stick to that